# Sai Baba's association with Hinduism

Tags: sai

Sai Baba is said to have stayed in a dilapidated mosque in Shirdi chanting 'Allah Malik'for 50 years. How did he come to be associated with Hindu beliefs? Did Sai Baba himself hold any beliefs about Shiva, Vishnu, Hanuman, etc?

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know sai baba is associated both hindu and muslim. 
sai baba is called avtar or lord shiva. for more detail information you can go here- http://askshirdisaibaba.in/ask-shirdi-sai-baba-question-answers-miracles-jadu-help-best-song-lyrics-aarti-wallpepar-hd-images-free-download-shayari-sms-messages-whatsapp-status-update-hindi/

Comment: You should cite some authentic source rather than citing some  site.